# Coprime automorphism group implies cyclic with order a cyclicity-forcing number

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory, automorphism-group

How do you prove Step 2 in Proof Outline, [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Coprime_automorphism_group_implies_cyclic_with_order_a_cyclicity-forcing_number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is the ($G$ is abelian by step $1$) Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $|P| \geq p^2$, then $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ (these are the only non-isomorphic groups or order $p^2$). In the first case $Aut(G)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $GL(2,p)$ and in the latter case to $\mathbb{Z}/p(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$. Since $|GL(2,p)|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ in both cases this violates $gcd(|G|,|Aut(G)|)=1$ by a factor $p$.

Note: observe that this cyclicity forcing is equivalent to $gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1$, where $|G|=n$ and $\varphi$ Euler's totient function.

Comment: It seems to me that you are saying that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. Why is this true? Are you using the fact that $P$ is a Sylow somehow? Where did you use that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: I am using that $G$ is abelian hence a direct product of its Sylow subgroups and hence you can easily extend the indicates automorphisms to the whole group.

Comment: If $G=G_1 \times G_2$, then $Aut(G_1)$ (and also $Aut(G_2))$ can be homomorphically embedded in $Aut(G)$: if $\alpha \in Aut(G_1)$, define $\phi_{\alpha} \in Aut(G)$ by $\phi_{\alpha}((g_1,g_2))=(\alpha(g_1),g_2)$. It is easy to check that this defines an automorphism of the whole group $G$, and the assignment $\alpha \mapsto \phi_{\alpha}$ is an injective homomorphism. So $Aut(G_1) \leq Aut(G)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Say that $H$ is a subgroup of $P$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. For your argument to work we need $H$ to be a direct summand of $G$, right? But why is that the case? What if $P\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: OK, now you can get your induction argument going: $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^2(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ and has an element of order $p$.